# I get a error code when i want to run a beautifulsoup code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Can someone explain to me how to error occures and how to fix it. im stuck.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get("https://www.onlinegrowlab.nl")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text , "lxml")

header = soup.find_all('h2', class_= 'article-card.horizontal' )

print(header)
```

error

```
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 
312, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `.text` to `html_text` and there's no `h2` in that class container. You can get the article headers from the `<a>` tag.

Here's how:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0",
}
html_text = requests.get("https://www.onlinegrowlab.nl", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text, "lxml")

header = [h.getText() for h in soup.select(".article-card header p a")]
print("\n".join(header))
```

Output:

```
Wat is Sundaeswap en hoe werkt het? Alles wat je moet weten
Beste cryptomunten top 10 (de beste projecten uitgelegd)
Strongblock – Alles wat je moet weten + mijn inkomsten
Wat is de IMU+ actie? Een complete uitleg en de speciale korting!
Hoe werkt cryptogeld? 8 meest gestelde vragen over crypto
Wat zijn NFT-games en hoe verdien je er geld mee!
```

Comment: thankss im just trying some things. Im new to this all so most of the things i try is just gibberish

Comment: Sorry for asking but why is the headers = {} necessary? what does is do and how do you know you need that version for the user agent?

Comment: [Learn more about User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this same issue when i was a beginner to learn this beautiful soup library.

My follwing guidance and reference code, it may be useful to you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get("https://www.onlinegrowlab.nl")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text , "lxml")
soup
print(soup.prettify())


title_html = soup.find_all(class_='article-card horizontal')

movie_titles = []

for title in title_html:
 movie_titles.append(title.text.strip())
print(movie_titles)
```

> output ;-

```
['link to Wat is Sundaeswap en hoe werkt het? Alles wat je moet weten\n\n\nWat is Sundaeswap en hoe werkt het? Alles wat je moet weten\n\n\nAls je wil weten wat Sundaeswap is heb ik hier het antwoord voor je: \n\n\n\nSundaeswap is een gedecentraliseerde exchange op het Cardano netwerk. Je kunt hierop cryptomunten inwisselen tegen andere...Lees verder', 'link to Beste cryptomunten top 10 (de beste projecten uitgelegd)\n\n\nBeste cryptomunten top 10 (de beste projecten uitgelegd)\n\n\nNa jaren bezig te zijn geweest met crypto en alle soorten projecten die daarbij horen, heb ik voor mezelf een lijst gemaakt. In die lijst staan de beste cryptomunten met de meeste potentie voor de...Lees verder', 'link to Strongblock – Alles wat je moet weten + mijn inkomsten\n\n\nStrongblock – Alles wat je moet weten + mijn inkomsten\n\n\nWat is StrongBlock\n\n\n\nStrongBlock is een project dat mensen helpt nodes op te zetten op een makkelijke manier. De gebruiker kan via Strongblock nodes aanmaken voor Ethereum, Polygon, Sentinel en...Lees verder', 'link to Wat is de IMU+ actie? Een complete uitleg en de speciale korting!\n\n\nWat is de IMU+ actie? Een complete uitleg en de speciale korting!\n\n\nIn dit artikel ga ik het hebben over de IMU+, want dat is het nieuwe programma waar ze mee bezig zijn. De jongens van de IMU zijn 360 graden gedraaid en de wereld staat op zijn kop!\n\n\n\nHet is iets...Lees verder', 'link to Hoe werkt cryptogeld? 8 meest gestelde vragen over crypto\n\n\nHoe werkt cryptogeld? 8 meest gestelde vragen over crypto\n\n\nHet lijkt wel of iedereen om je heen cryptogeld wilt hebben. Het is niet meer de vraag of je mee gaat doen, maar wanneer! Door de crypto hype ben ik een aantal jaar geleden ook begonnen met...Lees verder', "link to Wat zijn NFT-games en hoe verdien je er geld mee!\n\n\nWat zijn NFT-games en hoe verdien je er geld mee!\n\n\nHet afgelopen jaar was gekkenhuis met alle NFT's die werden uitgegeven en konden worden gebruikt in game. Ik ben zelf een groot fan van cryptogames, zoals gala games, The Sandbox en Axie infinitie....Lees verder"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but did you wanted to use this? :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get("https://www.onlinegrowlab.nl")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text , "lxml")

header = soup.find_all(class_= 'article-card horizontal' )

print(header)
```

Comment: This gives an empty list.

Comment: @baduker you were correct. This was because there was nothing to find with the old code.